# Python Plotly tri surf remove lines

Tags: python, plot, plotly

Is it possible to somehow remove (or maybe dim) the black lines of the triangles in the tri_surf plot from plotly in python, such that only smooth surfaces remain?

To be clear, I mean the following plotting function:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

ff.create_trisurf(x=x, y=y, z=z, colormap=color, simplices=cells)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- using https://plotly.com/python/trisurf/#mobius-band as sample
- you can make the **Scatter3d** lines trace invisible

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
import plotly.graph_objects as go

u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 24)
v = np.linspace(-1, 1, 8)
u, v = np.meshgrid(u, v)
u = u.flatten()
v = v.flatten()

tp = 1 + 0.5 * v * np.cos(u / 2.0)
x = tp * np.cos(u)
y = tp * np.sin(u)
z = 0.5 * v * np.sin(u / 2.0)

points2D = np.vstack([u, v]).T
tri = Delaunay(points2D)
simplices = tri.simplices

fig = ff.create_trisurf(
    x=x, y=y, z=z, colormap="Portland", simplices=simplices, title="Mobius Band"
)


# make lines invisible
fig.for_each_trace(
    lambda t: t.update(visible=False)
    if isinstance(t, go.Scatter3d) and t.mode == "lines"
    else t
)
fig.show()
```